# How to create left click button that deletes row in dataGridView Box?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[Here is](http://gyazo.com/a4fe7ad1583b4c50b91699e7ff601103) the data grid box I am working with.

I want to create a left click button that deletes the selected row.
I have this so far:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
        m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Delete Current Row"));
        m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Duplicate Row"));

        int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
        if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
        {
            m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(string.Format("Delete this row", currentMouseOverRow.ToString())));
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
            }
        }
        m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem ? What isn't workking in what you have so far ?

Comment: When I hover over the row and click the button I created, it will not delete or do anything

Comment: You should use the `MenuItem` constructor that accepts an EventHandler as second argument and put your delete code in that handler.

Comment: y aint u creating a cell as DataGridViewButton and on click of that button, delete that row?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean gulshanm01

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new event to your ContexMenu, "ItemClicked". It has the items, but no event.

My idea: use Designer to add one "ContexMenUStrip" from the "ToolBox". It appears to the bottom of the designer. Give it a name, like "DataGridContexMenu". Then select your datagrid, and set it's "ContexMenuStrip" to match your newly made "DataGridContexMenu".

Each time the datagrid is right-clicked, clear the old items from the "DataGridContexMenu". Add the wanted items, like you have done on your code:

```
DataGridContexMenu.Items.Clear();
```

You can use "Tag"-property to identify each item on the menu:

```
DataGridContexMenu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem()
            {
                Name = "Elements_Copy_ToolStripMenuItem",
                Tag = "Copy",
                Text = "Copy columns",
                ToolTipText = "Click to copy"
            });
```

Then add a new "ItemClicked" event to this "DataGridContexMenu" in the designer:

```
private void DataContextMenuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
   switch (e.ClickedItem.Tag.ToString())
   {
      case "Copy":
         // Your operations code here..
         break;
   }
}
```